# Optimization database

Tags: c#, mysql, sentence

I have a question about how to optimize my database :

I have a first table, where I set a list of elements (plates) with all its geometric definitions, that looks like that :

```
CONTRACT | NAME | CONTOURS |  HOLES  | SCRIBING
C1       | D001 | bigString|bigString|bigString
C1       | D003 | bigString|bigString|bigString
C2       | D003 | bigString|bigString|bigString
...
```

Then on a second table, I have a list of boxes (in fact they are big plates in which goes the plates of 1st table, I call it box not to make confusion), in each box I have a list of elements inside, and define it like this.

```
ID     | NAME | NAME_ELEMENT | CONTRACT_ELEMENT| QUANTITY | 
10001  | BOX1 |         D001 |               C1|     100  |
10001  | BOX1 |         D003 |               C1|     100  |
10001  | BOX1 |         D003 |               C2|     100  |
...
```

I don't link on ID, but on CONTRACT and NAME, it is volontary(the first table is only the table with geometric definitions).

The problem is I have a ListView with list of boxes, and when I click on one box, I need to display all of the elements inside the box.
For now I just do something like that :

```
    foreach(Plate plate in contexte.SelectedBox)
    {
       plate.GetGeometry();
    }
```

**Edit** : Forgot to say, my function GetGeometry is just a SQL request "SELECT * FROM DEFINITION_TABLE WHERE CONTRACT='C1' AND NAME='D001'.

It works good, but when I have a big plate, with hunders elements inside, it is very long, as it make hundreds of SELECT requests.

I see 2 ways to solve the problem :

1. In my box definition table, add the geometric informations of details. But is this correct, as it means copy all definitions in both tables.
2. Make a SQL request  kind of

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_DEFINITION 
WHERE (CONTRACT='C1' OR CONTRACT='C2') AND (NAME='D001' OR NAME='D003'...)
```

3. The request may be

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_DEFINITION 
WHERE (CONTRACT='C1' AND NAME='D001') OR (CONTRACT='C1' AND NAME='D003') OR (CONTRACT='C2' AND NAME='D003')...
```

But in the case I have hundreds details, the sentence would be very long.

I feel like 1st option is not the good one, and may use the 2nd one. What would you advise about it? Is it ok to make such a long sentence for MySQL? Am I limited on sentence length?

Edit : Thanks @Akina for editing post, could you please explain how you did to add spaces in table? I added spaces, but stack automatically deleted them all?

Comment: *I feel like 1st option is not the good one, and may use the 2nd one.* Your requests are NOT equivalent. You have no "options" - you have at least one (and even maybe both) illogical query.

Comment: @Akina first thanks for the edit (couldn't add spaces myself), then I understand 3rd query is not fully "correct", and would need a second filter at code level. So the 2nd would be the good one. But is it ok to make such a long query for MySQL? I mean if I have 200 elements for example.

Comment: Use the form `WHERE (CONTRACT, NAME) IN (('C1','D001'), ('C1','D003'), ('C2','D003'), ...)` - it takes less bytes. *is it ok to make such a long query for MySQL?* Look for [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value - your query text size must not exceed it (by default it is 64 Mbytes). Remember - if your literals list is over ~10 elements MySQL will sort it before using it in a query.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this syntax... Could you write it as answer so I could close the question please?

Comment: Not convinced by the data model you present.  There is/are no common column(s) in these tables that would allow a JOIN operation to succeed.

Comment: @v0rl0n in fact there is a reason for that, let's say in the same contract "C1" I can get 10-20 different details "D001", with some information that is for each specific detail (i.e quantities), but all "D001" have the same geometry, that's why I have a separate table only for geometry defenitions (and other parameters common to all D001). My "boxes" table is linked to the list of details by their ID, but to get geometry I filter on their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the form

```
WHERE (CONTRACT, NAME) IN (('C1','D001'), ('C1','D003'), ('C2','D003'), ...)
```

it takes less bytes.

> is it ok to make such a long query for MySQL?

Look for [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) value - your query text size must not exceed it (by default it is 64 Mbytes).

Remember - if your literals list is over ~10 elements MySQL will sort it before using it in a query.